# Lock the Entire individual Row immediately for other shared user to edit after a entry made in a cell in google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0P9EB.png)I have a Google spreadsheet with 7 Column.
I want to lock the particular row when entry made to column F of that particular row.

I want to lock only that row not entire Google Sheet, Other rows should be free to add entry.

Check the Picture, When any value comes to Column F, Entire Particular row should be Locked for further edit and Deletion.

Any help would be obliged.

Any help.
I would really obliged.

Regards
Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would fit your need. Change "Data" to the sheet you want it to happen.

```
function onEdit(e){
  const column = e.range.getColumn();
  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const value = e.value;
  const sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();
  //Change the sheet where you want the lock
  const criteriaSheet = "Data";
  //Change your email adres
  const owner = "yourEmail@email.com";
  
  if (value != "" && column == 6 && sheet == criteriaSheet){
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 1, 1, 6)
    .protect()
    .setDescription("Lock")
    .addEditor(owner);
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Getting Error Range is not defined ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I appreciate it. But unfortunately my problem still the same. check the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0P9EB.png 

If anyvalue comes to F coloumn respected row should be Lock to Deletion and Edit for other userr. 
Please help me little in details i am not a frequent developer.

Comment: See my updated code. Change the sheet name you want it to hapen + your email, only you can edit the range then.